# As verbs, what’s the difference between 经历 and 通过?

Tags: difference

I saw both of them translated as ‘go through’... But do they have any more specific use or meaning difference?

Answer (score 1):

[经历](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/7286/) (v): to experience; to go through.  e.g. 经历人生起伏 (experience life's up and downs)

[通过](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/9347/) (v): to pass through ; to get past. e.g. 通过隧道 (pass through the tunnel)

[通过](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/9347/) (v): to pass; to adopt.  e.g. 通过法案 (to pass/ to adopt a bill)

**Edit:**

> 经历 translated as "go through" is referring to 'go through an experience'

Example:

广岛曾经历过核弹轰炸 - Hiroshima experienced (went through) nuclear bombing

人人都会经历人生起伏 - Everyone will experience  (go through) life's up and downs

> 通过 translated as is referring to 'go through a physical path or go/ pass through an object'

Example:

火車通过隧道 - the train passes through a tunnel

Comment: Thank you so much Tang Ho! So as I understood, 经历 is more related with someone’s experience, right? Thank you!! 

Comment: @Greta : please see my edition at the bottom of my post

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! Much more clear right now!